# Changing the order of limits

Tags: calculus, continuity, partial-derivative

I'm looking for an example of a function $f(x,y)$ such that
 $$\lim_{x\to a}\{\lim_{y\to b} f(x,y)\}\neq \lim_{y\to b}\{\lim_{x\to a}f(x,y)\}$$

Comment: Are you asking for an example? What have you tried?

Comment: Yes  I need example

Comment: Without restrictions on what kind of bivariate function $f(x,y)$ is, examples are easy to formulate, with a bit of thought.  Expect that $f(x,y)$ might be *discontinuous* at $(a,b)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it fails to hold for some $f(x,y)$!!

Consider $f(x,y)=\dfrac{x+y^2}{x+y}.$

$\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\lim_{y\to 0}f(x,y)\right)=1$ and $\lim_{y\to 0}\left(\lim_{x\to 0}f(x,y)\right)=0$

Comment: Give examples for which it holds true.